# Pass selected values in Kendo Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I'm used Kendo MultiSelect in my mvc5 project.
So I have a View with multiselect:

```
@model Library.ViewModels.Models.BookViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
                    placeholder: "--Select Public Houses--",
                    dataTextField: "PublicHouseName",
                    dataValueField: "PublicHouseId",
                    autoBind: true,
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                dataType: "json",
                                url: "/book/getallpublichouses"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("#multiselect").getKendoMultiSelect().value([/* there  must be a string array of ID's of pre-selected values here*/]);
            });
        </script>
```

My BookViewModel looks like this:

```
public class BookViewModel
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 15 characters")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string AuthorName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
        [Range(1, 2019, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 1 and 2019")]
        public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }

        public List<int> PubHouses { get; set; }
        public  ICollection<PublicHouseViewModel> PublicHouses { get; set; }

    }
```

The property `public List<int> PubHouses { get; set; }` contains a List of ID's which must be pre-selected in kendo MultiSelect.

So how can I pass this list of int in property `BookViewModel.PubHouses` like string array in kendo MultiSelect?

Comment: You can convert you property to a javascript array using `var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PubHouses))`. But why not just bind to you model in the first place using `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.PubHouses, ...)`? And why are you making an ajax call to get the options instead of passing it to the view in the first place?

Comment: sorry, I'm new in javascript

Comment: `<script>
            var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PubHouses));
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
                    placeholder: "--Select Public Houses--",
                    /*----------------------------------------------*/
                    }
                });
                $("#multiselect").getKendoMultiSelect().value(values);
            });
        </script>`         //Can I do like this??

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, but it's dont wokr. Or maybe  I did something wrong.

Comment: Inspect the result of `values` in the console - it will be an array of the ID's that you have said you wanted